# Automatic synchronization of Ubuntu one on specific time every day

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one

Can I start Ubuntu One synchronization from my 12.10 Ubuntu Desktop on specific time automatically everyday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to a [similar question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/93972) in Launchpad, it seems there is no official way of doing this.

But, you can always create a CRON job for doing this.

You can use the command-line tool `u1sdtool` for controlling your Ubuntu One Sync Daemon.

For eg, you can use:
`u1sdtool --connect` to connect to your Ubuntu One account and
`u1sdtool --disconnect` to disconnect from your Ubuntu One account

Say you want to start your synchronization at 3am in the morning and stop at 6am, then in effect you will be creating two CRON job entries.

> 0 3 * * * u1sdtool --connect
>   0 3 * * * u1sdtool --disconnect

---

**References:**
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/93972

Comment: You cannot do this with a cron job so easily. Commands run from cron have a pretty much empty environment, and so the commands won't be able to connect to the existing syncdaemon process, which u1sdtool communicates with via dbus.